# Использование контейнера указателей для присваивания значений членам класса

Tags: c++, указатели, контейнеры

Проблема в том что у меня много различных членов-переменных в классе , для того что бы не писать функцию со множеством параметров я решил инициализировать указатели следующим образом. Я создаю контейнер помещаю туда те члены класса которые мне нужно инициализировать и передаю по ссылке в функцию, там соответственно перебираю контейнер и присваиваю каждому элементу значение , проблема в том что присваивания не происходит. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Sample {
public :
    Sample() {
        std::vector<int*> cont = { a, b };
        iniVector(cont);
    }
    int* Get_A() { return a; }
    int* Get_B() { return b; }
private:
    void iniVector(std::vector<int*>& vec_p_int) {
        int _a = 10;
        int _b = 20;
        int* _a_p = &_a;
        int* _b_p = &_b;
        vec_p_int[0] = _a_p;
        vec_p_int[1] = _b_p;
    }
    int* a = NULL;
    int* b = NULL;
};
int main()
{
    Sample* smaple = new Sample();
    printf("%d", *smaple->Get_A());
    printf("%d", *smaple->Get_B());
}
```

Comment: Вы в вектор `std::vector<int*> cont = { a, b };` записываете копии значений переменных `a` и `b`. А их значения нигде не меняете.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ваш вектор в конструкторе является локальным объектом, он
   уничтожается сразу после конструирования объекта. И зачем для двух объектов(указателей) нужен вектор, непонятно...
2. Нет у вас в классе много  различных членов-переменных, а есть два
   указателя, присутствие которых обязывает вас писать как минимум
   конструктор копирования, оператор присваивания и деструктор.
3. Вы пытаетесь инициализировать члены_указатели в функции, адресами
   локальных объектов этих функций, которые тоже уничтожаются сразу
   после вызова функции, и на что будут указывать ваши указатели?...

Куда лучше держать в классе просто объекты и работать с ними. То что вы хотите сделать это:

```
class Sample {
public:
    Sample(int _a = 10,  int _b = 20)
        : a(_a), b(_b)  { }    
    int Get_A() const { return a; }
    int Get_B() const { return b; }
private:    
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main()
{
    Sample* smaple = new Sample;
    printf("%d", smaple->Get_A());
    printf("%d", smaple->Get_B());
    delete smaple;
}
```

И не нужна  вся ваша возня непонятная... Если не устраивает, расскажите подробно чего вы хотите добиваться.

Comment: Это я привел пример , это не рабочий код. Я хотел понять почему нельзя сделать таким образом,что кладешь в массив или контейнер указатели и инициализируешь их в функции , при чем в самой функции происходит выделение памяти и этим указателям в контейнере присваиваются новые адреса. Я понял что при выходе из функции освобождается память и те указатели становятся не действительными. Я понял , получается что можно сделать только так .

Comment: `class Sample_2 {
public:
 Sample_2() {
  a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  b = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

  int* arr[2] = { a,b };
  iniArr(arr);
  a = arr[0];
  b = arr[1];
 }`

Comment: @Денис Яковлев, нет, можно делать по разному, но нужно сначала понять что вы хотите сделать, а вы в вопросе об этом не рассказали. Нужно написать что имеете и что хотите получать

Comment: ~~~skjskjdskjdksksjdksjdksjdkjskjsdjskdjksjdksj~~~

Answer (score 0):

Это мое решение, я по глупости забыл что созданная в функции переменная удалякется после выхода из функции.
  typedef int* point;
    typedef double* Direction;

```
enum someType{Tangent, Normal};
class Sample_3 {
public :
    Sample_3(){
        // допустим мы хотим инициализировать точку и провести из нее два направления друг другу перпендикулярные
        std::vector<someType> typesForDir = { Normal, Tangent };
        // Необходимо инициализировать одну точку и два направления через функцию inizilize
        std::vector<Direction> iniDirections{ this->dir_p_1_x, this->dir_p_1_y };
        inizilize(5.0, this->p_1, typesForDir, iniDirections);
        // инициализируем теперь точку 2 а из нее нам нужно направление тангенциальное
        std::vector<someType> typFor_dir_p2_y{ Tangent };
        std::vector<Direction> dirr{ this->dir_p_2_y };
        inizilize(10.0, this->p_2, typFor_dir_p2_y, dirr);
        //Ну и так далее 
        //Суть в том что бы не дубиловать код в отдельных функциях инициализации для point и dirrection , есть смысл их инициализировать вместе
        // Но мы точно знаем что точка может быть одна а вот направлений из этой точки может быть множество, так вот 
        //как инициализировать переменные класса заранее положив их в контейнер.
        // Мое решение это следеющее
        // Так как вектор изменяется в функции то мы просто присвоим членам классам значения из вектора

        dir_p_1_x = iniDirections[0];
        dir_p_1_y = iniDirections[1];

    }
    point Get_p_1() {
        return this->p_1;
    }
    Direction Get_member_1_t2() {
        return this->dir_p_1_x;
    }

private :

    point p_1 = NULL;
    point p_2 = NULL;
    point p_3 = NULL;

    Direction dir_p_1_x = NULL;
    Direction dir_p_1_y = NULL;
    Direction dir_p_2_y = NULL;
    Direction dir_p_3_x = NULL;

private:
    //В связи стем что инициализация точки и направления отличается одной строчкой кода, то 
    //нет необходимости дублировать код а все поместить в одну функцию
    void inizilize(double offset/*I*/
        , point& p_1 /*O*/, std::vector<someType> typesForDirr /*Input*/,
        std::vector<Direction>& cretedDir /*Output*/ ) {
        //Инициализация точки и контейнера с направлением 

    }

};
```